# Windows 7 not showing in grub after ubuntu install

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub

After installing ubuntu 12 windows 7 is not showing in my grub anymore
can you help?

i have done a grub-update etc.

this is my boot script info

```
                      Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Lilo is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Lilo is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 72 for .
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdd.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe /wubildr 
                       /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr /wubildr.mbr 
                       /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/lilo.conf /boot/map

sdc1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdc2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdc5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  According to the info in the boot sector, sdc5 starts 
                       at sector 2048.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdd1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 115.0 GB, 115033153536 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13985 cylinders, total 224674128 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048   224,671,743   224,669,696   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 3,907,029,167 3,907,029,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1           2,048   195,311,615   195,309,568 Data partition (Windows/Linux)

Drive: sdc _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdc: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdc1    *          2,048   104,857,599   104,855,552   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sdc2         104,859,647 1,948,286,383 1,843,426,737   f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sdc5         104,859,648 1,948,286,383 1,843,426,736   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


Drive: sdd _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdd: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdd1                  63   976,751,999   976,751,937   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        8058C68B58C67F80                       ntfs       OCZ SSD
/dev/sdb1        11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5   ext4       
/dev/sdc1        D088697688695BCA                       ntfs       Firefox Downloads
/dev/sdc5        F40A8D220A8CE2CA                       ntfs       Overige
/dev/sdd1        00CC96FACC96E964                       ntfs       WD

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /media/toby/OCZ SSD      fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdb1        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdc1        /media/toby/Firefox Downloads fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdc5        /media/toby/Overige      fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sdd1        /media/toby/WD           fuseblk    (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)


=========================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd1,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5' {
recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-advanced-11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5' {
    recordfail
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-17-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.0-17-generic-recovery-11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5' {
    recordfail
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd1,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-17-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic root=UUID=11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd1,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,gpt1  11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
if [ "x${timeout}" != "x-1" ]; then
  if keystatus; then
    if keystatus --shift; then
      set timeout=-1
    else
      set timeout=0
    fi
  else
    if sleep --interruptible 3 ; then
      set timeout=0
    fi
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
menuentry "Windows 8" {
    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
    chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sdb1/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

============================= sdb1/etc/lilo.conf: ==============================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/lilo.conf  -   systemwide LILO configuration (LILO 23)
# details see in manpages: lilo(8) and lilo.conf(5)

# +-------------------------------------------------------------+
# |                        !! Reminder !!                       |
# |                                                             |
# | Don't forget to run 'lilo' after you make changes to this   |
# | conffile or you have installed a new kernel.                |
# +-------------------------------------------------------------+


# #################### LILO global section ######################

# With all newer systems (until year 2004) you can use the RAM
# above 15 MB. This option allows the use of this range of RAM.
#large-memory

# With all newer systems you can boot from any partition on disks 
# with more than 1024 cylinders. This option allows the use of 
# partitions above 1024 cylinders.
lba32

# Specifies the boot device.  This is where Lilo installs its boot
# block.  It can be either a partition, or the raw device, in which
# case it installs in the MBR, and will overwrite the current MBR.
# With newer kernel you should use the ID of the boot device, which
# can be found here: /dev/disks/by-id/ata*.
#boot = /dev/sdb
boot = /dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDS722020ALA330_JK1171YAGVD55N

# This option may be needed for some software RAID installs.
#raid-extra-boot = mbr-only

# Enable map compaction.  This tries to merge read requests for 
# adjacent sectors into a single read request. This drastically 
# reduces load time and keeps the map smaller.  Using 'compact' 
# is especially recommended when booting from a floppy disk.  
# It is disabled here by default because it doesn't always work.
#compact

# Set the verbose level for bootloader installation. Value range:
# 0 to 5. Default value is 0.
#verbose = 1

# Specifies the location of the map file. Lilo creates the (sector) 
# map file of direct sector addresses which are independent of any
# filesystem.
map = /boot/map

# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Specifies the menu interface. You have the choice between:
#   text: simple text menu with black background and white text
#   menu: configurable text menu with background and text colors.
#   bmp:  graphical menu with 640x480 bitmap background.
install = menu

# A) Customized boot message for choice 'text'.
# For the simple text menu you can set an extra message in the 
# created file. Its text will be displayed before boot prompt.
#message = /boot/message.txt

# B) Configuration of the scheme for choice 'menu'.
# Use following coding: <text>:<highlight>:<border>:<title>
# The first character of each part sets the text frontcolor, 
# the second character of earch part sets the text backcolor,
# an upper-case character sets bold face text (frontcolor).
# i.g. 'menu-scheme=wm:rw:wm:Wm'. Possible colors: 
# k=black, b=blue, g=green, c=cyan, r=red, m=magenta, y=yellow, w=white.
menu-scheme = Wb:Yr:Wb:Wb
#menu-title = " DESDEMONA Boot-Manager "

# C) Configuration of the image for choice 'bmp'.
# For the graphical menu you need a bitmap file, which needs a special
# menu configuration in the file header (see: lilo -E). Ideally you 
# use one of the delivered images of the lilo package.
#   with 16 colors:    onlyblue, tuxlogo, inside
#   with 256 colors:   coffee
#   for Debian:        debianlilo, debian, debian-de
#bitmap = /boot/tuxlogo.bmp

# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Specifies the number of deciseconds (0.1 seconds) how long LILO 
# should wait before booting the first image.  LILO doesn't wait if
# 'delay' is omitted or set to zero. You do not see the defined menu.
#delay = 20

# Prompt to start one certain kernel from the displayed menu.
# It is very recommeded to also set 'timeout'. Without timeout boot 
# will not take place unless you hit return. Timeout is the number
# of deciseconds (0.1 seconds) after there the default image will 
# be started. With 'single-key' alias numbers for each menu line can
# be used.
prompt
timeout = 100
#single-key

# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Specifying the VGA text mode that should be selected when booting.
# The following values are recognized (case is ignored):
#   vga=normal    80x25 text mode (default)
#   vga=extended  80x50 text mode (abbreviated to 'ext')
#   vga=ask       stop and ask for user input: choice of text mode
#   vga=<mode>    use the corresponding text mode number. A list of  
#                   available modes can be obtained by booting with  
#                   vga=ask'  and then pressing [Enter].
# Another way is the use of frame buffer mode. Then the kernel 
# will switch from the normal vga text mode (80x25) to the frame
# buffer mode (if frame buffer support is in the kernel):
#   vga=0x314      800x600 @ 16 bit
#   vga=0x317     1024x768 @ 16 bit
#   vga=0x318     1024x768 @ 24 bit
#vga = ask
vga = normal
#vga = 0x317

# ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Kernel command line options that apply to all installed images go
# here.  See 'kernel-parameters.txt' in the Linux kernel 'Documentation'
# directory. I.g. for start into 'init 5' write:  append="5"
#append = ""

# If you used a serial console to install Debian, this option should be
# enabled by default.
#serial = 0,9600

# Set the image which should be started after delay or timeout.
# If not set, the first defined image will be started.
#default = Linux


# ################### LILO per-image section ####################

# Each image is configured with the linux kernel (=image) and
# usually with the initrd file. Configure all GNU/Linux systems
# on other partitions, too.

image = /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
    label = "Linux"
    #root = /dev/sdb1
    root = "UUID=11d0c7d7-5e6d-48cc-80b3-709e5b8e80c5"
    read-only
#   restricted
#   alias = 1
#   optional
    initrd = /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

               =                boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
               =                boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic               1
               =                boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic                  1
               =                initrd.img                                     1
               =                initrd.img.old                                 1
               =                vmlinuz                                        1

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already mounted all of your HDD Partitions? You should try to reinstall grub with:

```
# To view all your partitions
sudo fdisk -l
```

then mount your linux partition with:

```
# pay attention to the number of your linux partition. 
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
```

and finally:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Then, reboot and check if it worked. After repairing grub, you can try `sudo update-grub` again..